# Do you prepare a new application (stand alone exe file) for admin or handle it in the same application by access rights?

Tags: executable

Do you prepare a new application (stand alone exe file) for admin or handle it in the same application by access rights?

Answer (score 0):

### It's always a case-by-case situation.

I doubt there's a generic response to this question.

For example:

- If there's much overlap between the admin features/data and these of the regular application, a single application with access right and dynamic/polymorphic views is probably preferable.
- If security is of utmost importance, two separate applications may make sense: users with the lesser enabled application will never get to admin features no matter how hard they try or how some bug let them.
- If there are multiple levels of access, a single application may make sense (rather than managing as many as there are levels (or possibly combinations thereof...)
- ...